# How to access multidimensional array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

```
$.ajax({

    url : 'phpscript/eventDayRender.php',
    type: 'POST',
    async : false,
    global : false,
    success:function(data){

        var obj = JSON.parse(data);

        var len = parseInt(obj.total);

        //var rack_count = Object.keys(obj['data']).length;

        //console.log(rack_count);

        for(var k=0; k < len; k++){

            html +='<tr>';

      //Here i am not able to access the value day-min.js:137
      //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at Object.success (day-min.js:137)
                html +='<td><div class="slot">'+obj[k][0]+'</div></td>'; 
                html +='<td><div class="rack">Hello</div></td>';
                html +='<td><div class="rack">Hello</div></td>';

            html +='</tr>';
        }
    }
});
```

array is something like

```
{
  "data": {
    "12:00 am to 04:00 am": {
      "bookings": {
        "user": "Rishabh",
        "date": "2019-3-31",
        "slot": "08:00 pm to 12:00 am",
        "rack": "1"
      }
    },
    "04:00 am to 08:00 am": {
      "bookings": {
        "user": "Rishabh",
        "date": "2019-3-31",
        "slot": "08:00 pm to 12:00 am",
        "rack": "1"
      }
    },
    "08:00 am to 12:00 pm": {
      "bookings": {
        "user": "Rishabh",
        "date": "2019-3-31",
        "slot": "08:00 pm to 12:00 am",
        "rack": "1"
      }
    },
    "12:00 pm to 04:00 pm": {
      "bookings": {
        "user": "Rishabh",
        "date": "2019-3-31",
        "slot": "08:00 pm to 12:00 am",
        "rack": "1"
      }
    },
    "04:00 pm to 08:00 pm": {
      "bookings": {
        "user": "Rishabh",
        "date": "2019-3-31",
        "slot": "08:00 pm to 12:00 am",
        "rack": "1"
      }
    },
    "08:00 pm to 12:00 am": {
      "bookings": {
        "user": "Rishabh",
        "date": "2019-3-31",
        "slot": "08:00 pm to 12:00 am",
        "rack": "1"
      }
    }
  },
  "total": "6"
}
```

In this i want to access 12:00 am to 04:00 am but when i passing the argument in loop is giving the above error..

Comment: Your example does not have arrays.

Comment: its a json encode given below

Comment: Again, you **do not have an array** and this is the reason for your error.  .

Comment: I'm with PM 77-1 on this -- an array is a series of values/objects wrapped in square brackets.  Your data object should return something like `"data": [ {"12:00 am to 04:00 am":{...}}, {"04:00 am to 08:00 am": {...}}, ... ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot index object like this. You need to pass the key, which in the above case is "12:00 am to 04:00 am". So you can access it via `obj.data["12:00 am to 04:00 am"]`.

If you want to iterate over object use the following way.

```
for (var key in obj.data) {
    if (obj.data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + obj.data[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: And how i can access as same the bookings data in above.
"bookings": {
        "user": "Rishabh",
        "date": "2019-3-31",
        "slot": "08:00 pm to 12:00 am",
        "rack": "1"
      }

Comment: I don't think you need to iterate over `booking` as it has fixed keys. You can directly access `bookings.user`, `bookings.date` and so on.